# Tracert on Windows Returns Slower than on Linux

Tags: windows, linux, traceroute

I have two computers, one Windows and one Linux sitting side by side on my desk, both connecting to the same internet.  If I run a tracert on www.stackoverflow.com and traceroute www.stackoverflow.com, both return the same data.  However, tracert on Windows takes 3x as long (with the same params) as traceroute on Linux (linux tr is almost instantaneous)

I tried tracert -d but no real difference to speak of.

How can I get Windows tracert to return at the same speed?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows `tracert` tool sends [ICMP echo requests](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tracert.mspx?mfr=true); many routers will just `DROP` ICMP echo requests. Thus the tool must wait for an internal timeout before declaring that route dead.

The Linux `traceroute` tool sends UDP connection attempts; routers have to forward these packets, so it works pretty reliably. This means the tool won't have to wait for timeouts from most of the routers along the way.

Comment: As an addition to this, i believe there is a traceroute plugin for cygwin, so you can get linuxesque traceroutes on windows.

Comment: This is from a comment an anonymous user left behind but got rejected (invalid message edit): `This answer is wrong for three reasons: 1) Few if any Internet routers drop ICMP packets 2) Linux/Unix traceroute uses UDP, not TCP 3) The use of ICMP versus UDP has no real affect on speed

The answer below (Windows waits 1 second between hops) is the true and accurate answer.`

Comment: @Chris: Many thanks for the notice! I don't know how I wrote TCP in the first place, and I'm embarrassed that it took a _year_ for it to be corrected. But I stand by the "drop ICMP packets" portion -- I've seen that exact behavior too many times, especially on networks where a security-paranoid person thinks they'll "improve security" by dropping far too many packet types.

Answer (score 13):

The Windows `tracert` waits about 1 second between hops. The Linux `traceroute` does not wait between hops. There is no documented option for the Windows `tracert` to disable this delay.

Answer (score 8):

Stumbled upon this old thread and wanted to say that there is an option to speed up tracert in Windows.

tracert -d -w 100

-d prevents hostname resolution

-w 100 sets the response timeout to 100ms.

You may get a missed ping reply if your pinging slow network gear over a VPN or distant MPLS, but it speeds up the tracert to about 40 seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a tip, you can speed up traceroute in Windows by disabling resolving with `tracert -d`.

Answer (score 2):

`tracert` sends the probes one by one, `traceroute` sends 16 at a time (can be changed with the -N argument).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Please explain what the OP needs to do.